# Run private strong-named assemblies side-by-side

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-assembly, assemblies

I have an application depending on version `1.0` of `Assembly A` (which is strongly named and deployed privately in `bin` folder).  The application also loads `Assembly B` via reflection.  The complication is that `Assembly B` depends on version `2.0` of `Assembly A`, which is also strongly named and to be deployed privately.

Now I could configure the CLR to load `2.0` whenever `1.0` is requested and thus only have to deploy version `2.0`.  However, this means later when `Assembly B` is updated to depend on another version of `Assembly A`, I have to reconfigure the redirection.  Therefore, I'd prefer to have both versions of `Assembly A` run side-by-side in the my application.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have run into the same issue. I took the coward's way out, and renamed one of the assemblies. Looking forward to an answer :)